# они шли, но осторожно, и ещё осторожнее

Tags: пунктуация

> Какое-то время путешественники шли по тропе, так как она казалась самым лёгким путём вниз, но осторожно **?**  и ещё осторожнее - когда дорога привела их в тёмный лес и стала шире и ровнее.

Перевод с английского. В оригинале на месте **?** стоит запятая, в переводе запятой нет. Поскольку правила пунктуации в русском и английском отличаются, никак не могу определиться, нужна здесь запятая, или нет (по интонации - вроде и нужна, но как её обосновать?).

Можно пояснить ситуацию и ткнуть меня носом в соответствующее правило?

Оригинальный текст:

> > They followed the track for some while, for it offered much the easiest way down, but they went cautiously, and their anxiety increased as they came into the dark woods, and the path grew plainer and broader.

Comment: Нельзя ткнуть. См. мой ответ. А вот оригинал английского текста бы не помешал для понимания ситуации.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите оригинал текста.

Comment: @Vera Добавил текст на английском.

Comment: @behemotus Добавил текст на английском. Автор текст не зажал - он просто сейчас не в лучшем состоянии из-за внезапно свалившейся простуды.

Comment: К сожалению, сам перевод (удачный он или нет) желательно оставить в текущем виде. Вопрос только в правильной расстановке знаков препинания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нужна запятая, поскольку "но осторожно" относится к действию сказуемого до обозначенного момента (до подхода к тёмному лесу), а "ещё осторожнее" - к его действию после этого момента. Поэтому уточняющий оборот "но осторожно" по смыслу не может включать в себя следующее за ним "ещё осторожнее", а в результате его обособления после "осторожно" оказывается запятая.

**P.S.** Такая русская фраза вполне возможна, но на всякий случай - перевод (здесь своя грамматика).

*Какое-то время они двигались проторенным путём, ибо это сулило самый лёгкий спуск, но шли они с осторожностью, и их обеспокоенность усилилась при заходе в темную рощу; тропа же стала более пологой и широкой.*

Comment: "...и их обеспокоенность усилилась при заходе в темную рощу; тропа же стала более пологой и широкой". Мне это кажется неверным, нет там точки с запятой. .Нужно так: "..и их обеспокоенность усилилась, когда они зашли в темный лес и тропа стала более пологой и широкой".

Comment: Их запятая не слабее нашей точки запятой и просто так не появилась бы перед and; я бы сказал, она заканчивает оборот с 'as', чтобы устранить логическую связь обеспокоенности с пологим или широким характером тропы, в отличие от зловещего  влияния тёмного леса.

Comment: А мне кажется, что широкая дорога их как раз и не устраивала, на ней с большей вероятностью можно было с кем-либо встретиться.

Comment: Нет: в самом начале был сделан выбор идти единственной проторенной тропой. С предсказуемым уменьшением её крутизны и расширением страшнее не должно было стать, зато в тёмном лесу мог кто угодно прятаться. Если же логически объединить мнимую открытость тропы и закрытось леса, такой фактор беспокойства будет внутренне противоречив.

Answer (score 2):

Для удобства чтения и понимания:

Какое-то время путешественники **шли по тропе** (так как она казалась самым лёгким путём вниз), **но осторожно**, и ещё осторожнее - когда дорога привела их в тёмный лес и стала шире и ровнее.

Здесь можно рассматривать фразу как ССП с союзом И, при этом второе предложение является неполным, пропущено "они шли", пропуск обозначен тире.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

ДРУГОЙ ВАРИАНТ (близкий к английскому тексту)

Какое-то время путешественники шли по тропе,так как она казалась самым лёгким путём вниз, но  шли осторожно, и с еще большей осторожностью - когда дорога привела их в тёмный лес и стала шире и ровнее.

Answer (score 0):

Очень неудачный перевод (шли по тропе, так как..., но осторожно), а так-то запятая, конечно, нужна.
Не сразу и поймёшь, что "осторожно" относится к "шли".

Comment: Да как сказать... По мне "осторожно" вполне можно и нужно отнесли к шли, а вот "осторожно и еще осторожнее" - это не по-русски.

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя ткнуть. В русском нет подобной конструкции как наречие + тоже наречие в сравнительной степени. Потому как не с чем с сравнивать получается, а без этого в русском никак. А вообще два наречия через союх и никаких запятых не требуют. Так что пунктуация правильная, а вот фраза сама по себе плохая.

С чего там Alex_ander взял, что это к разным моментам относится - шут его знает. В английском это точно не так. это вполне себе однородные члены, просто пунктуация такова, что запятая нужна даже в этом случае, а в русском такого просто быть не может.

Стилистически (даже грамматически, пожалуй) правильно будет сказать

**"... шли... осторожно, очень осторожно, ...."** или как-то еще, а пунктуацию смотреть в зависимости от выбранного варианта.

Comment: СМЫСЛ,я думаю, здесь ТАКОЙ: по тропе идти опасно, но это самая легкая дорога, поэтому они выбрали ее, но шли осторожно. Когда дорога стала шире, ровнее и пошла через лес, опасность нежелательных встреч увеличилась, потому надо было идти еще осторожнее. Так что запятая на месте, она разделяет две части предложения, связанных союзом И.

Comment: А чего гадать-то, если автор английский текст зажал?